# Unable to decode stream: java.io.FileNotFoundException: No such file or directory)

Tags: android, image, compression, chat

I am trying to compress files before uploading them to firebese.

> Unfortunately nothing is happening just this:Unable to decode stream:
>   java.io.FileNotFoundException:
>   /com.marijan.red.MessageActivity@dac48b3/document/image:256 (No such
>   file or directory)

```
@Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (requestCode == GALLERY_PICK && resultCode == RESULT_OK){
           Uri imageUri = data.getData();

            DatabaseReference user_message_push = reference.child("Chats")
                    .child(fuser.getUid()).child(userid).push();

            final String push_id = user_message_push.getKey();

            final StorageReference filePath = mImageStorage.child("message_images").child(push_id +"jpg");

            File actualImage = new File (imageUri.getPath());
            try {
                Bitmap compressedImage = new Compressor(this)
                        .setQuality(50)
                        .compressToBitmap(actualImage);
                ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                compressedImage.compress(CompressFormat.JPEG, 50, baos);
                byte[] final_image = baos.toByteArray();

                UploadTask uploadTask = filePath.putBytes(final_image);

                Task<Uri> urlTask = uploadTask.continueWithTask(new Continuation<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot, Task<Uri>>() {
                    @Override
                    public Task<Uri> then(@NonNull Task<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot> task) throws Exception {
                        if (!task.isSuccessful()) {
                            throw task.getException();
                        }


                        return filePath.getDownloadUrl();
                    }
                }).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Uri>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Uri> task) {
                        if (task.isSuccessful()) {

                            String download_url = task.getResult().toString();

                            HashMap<String, Object> hashMap = new HashMap<>();
                            hashMap.put("sender", fuser.getUid());
                            hashMap.put("receiver",userid );
                            hashMap.put("message", download_url);
                            hashMap.put("isseen", false);
                            hashMap.put("type","image");

                            reference.push().setValue(hashMap);
```

I am assuming that I am not passing the ImageUri correctly

Comment: Check if asked READ_PERMISSION in runtime (SDK >= 23) & manifest

Comment: your `imageUri` is ok, but `imageUri.getPath()` is not - it does not point to any valid path

Comment: how should I do it?

Answer (score 0):

You have to use file provider [you can get knowledge from [here]](https://www.journaldev.com/23219/android-capture-image-camera-gallery-using-fileprovider). or you can get bitmap from your `uri` and you have to use content resolver like this

`Bitmap bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getContentResolver(), uri);`

So now you can compress your Bitmap before uploading.

**Another way** to get valid path from `uri`. And it vary for device os,. you can call. **Here path is String**

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
             path = getImageRealPath(getContentResolver(), uri, null);
  } else {
      path = uri.getPath();
   }

private String getImageRealPath(ContentResolver contentResolver, Uri uri, String whereClause) {
        String ret = "";

        // Query the uri with condition.
        Cursor cursor = contentResolver.query(uri, null, whereClause, null, null);

        if (cursor != null) {
            boolean moveToFirst = cursor.moveToFirst();
            if (moveToFirst) {

                // Get columns name by uri type.
                String columnName = MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA;
                Log.d("UriTest: ", "uri: " + uri);
                if (uri == MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI) {
                    columnName = MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA;
                }


                // Get column index.
                int imageColumnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(columnName);

                // Get column value which is the uri related file local path.
                ret = cursor.getString(imageColumnIndex);
            }
        }

        return ret;
    }
```

**Note: You have to check storage read permission first.**

Comment: Uri imageUri = data.getData(); Is there any way to clear the uri after it has been compressed?

Comment: Your imageUri is a local variable. So it will be cleared. And also this local variable is using in onActivityResult. So when onActivityResult call then imageUri will be called with valid condition. So imageUri will be use each onActivityResult  call with valid condition..

Comment: I managed to send and compress images , but now I have a problem I can send only on image. When I try the second time I doesn’t work the image Being sent, But when I close the activity and open it again and try to send the image it sends it. There must be something wrong maybe when I send the first image the seconds image uri is just being added one the first

Comment: It will depend on your code,  how you take image by button click or other. Or you are take multiple image or not. I don`t know what you wrote for image taken. But in this thread your problem was **File not found exception** If my answer solve your problem then you can accept it.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I solved it:
Now I have a new problem. I can upload only one image then I have to close the activity and open it again to send a new one. I assume that the imageuri of the first image stays saved and just get added on the first image

```
 private String getRealPathFromURI(Uri contentURI) {
    String result;
    Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(contentURI, null, null, null, null);
    if (cursor == null) { // Source is Dropbox or other similar local file path
        result = contentURI.getPath();
    } else {
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        int idx = cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.DATA);
        result = cursor.getString(idx);
        cursor.close();
    }
    return result;

}
 public  boolean isWriteStoragePermissionGranted() {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23) {
        if (checkSelfPermission(android.Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
                == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            Log.v(TAG,"Permission is granted2");
            return true;
        } else {

            Log.v(TAG,"Permission is revoked2");
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, 2);
            return false;
        }
    }
    else { //permission is automatically granted on sdk<23 upon installation
        Log.v(TAG,"Permission is granted2");
        return true;
    }
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (requestCode == GALLERY_PICK && resultCode == RESULT_OK){
        Uri selectedImageURI = data.getData();
        File imageFile = new File(getRealPathFromURI(selectedImageURI));

        DatabaseReference user_message_push = reference.child("Chats")
                .child(fuser.getUid()).child(userid).push();
        final String push_id = user_message_push.getKey();

        final StorageReference filePath = mImageStorage.child("message_images").child(push_id +"jpg");

        try {
            Bitmap compressedImage = new Compressor(this)
                    .setQuality(50)
                    .compressToBitmap(imageFile);
            ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            compressedImage.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 50, baos);
            final byte[] finalImage = baos.toByteArray();

            UploadTask uploadTask = filePath.putBytes(finalImage);
            Task<Uri> urlTask = uploadTask.continueWithTask(new Continuation<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot, Task<Uri>>() {
                @Override
                public Task<Uri> then(@NonNull Task<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot> task) throws Exception {
                    if (!task.isSuccessful()) {
                        throw task.getException();
                    }


                    return filePath.getDownloadUrl();
                }
            }).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Uri>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Uri> task) {
                    if (task.isSuccessful()) {

                        String download_url = task.getResult().toString();

                        HashMap<String, Object> hashMap = new HashMap<>();
                        hashMap.put("sender", fuser.getUid());
                        hashMap.put("receiver",userid );
                        hashMap.put("message", download_url);
                        hashMap.put("isseen", false);
                        hashMap.put("type","image");

                        reference.push().setValue(hashMap);
```